# Someone or somewhere to get Tebori Tattoo in/around Osaka

Tags: japan, osaka

Can anyone please help by pointing me in the direction of someone in the Osaka area (up to 1 hour travel around) where I can get a small/medium Tebori/Irezumi tattoo. I understand this is more of a discreet thing in Japan so it is harder to find of someone, so therefore I have not found anywhere so far.

I will be there in late March into April for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Google searched some tattoo artists in the Osaka area that have more positive than negative feedback and, although I am not recommending any of them (as I haven't personally used their services), if I were to get one myself I'd probably inquire from the following (random order):

1. Nine State Design

   - https://ninestatedesign.com (Mostly in Japanese, but lots of sample photos, price list, artist info in English, etc.)
   - 41 Google feedback with 4.9 average score, very few (if any) negative feedback
   - 22-min train ride from JR Osaka Station
   - [Map](https://g.page/ninestatedesign?share)
2. Body Blast Tattoo

   - https://bodyblasttattoo.jimdofree.com/ (In Japanese only, lots of photos)
   - 86 Google feedback with 4.9 average score, very few (if any) negative feedback
   - 28-min train ride from JR Osaka Station
   - [Map](https://goo.gl/maps/aRPeM7RPakiHKYbx6)
3. Three Tides Tattoo Osaka

   - http://www.threetidestattoo.com/aboutus/osaka (Mostly Japanese-English bilingual but few sample photos)
   - 99 Google feedback with 4.0 average score, but some negative feedback mostly from 1-2 yrs ago
   - 14-min train ride from JR Osaka Station
   - [Map](https://goo.gl/maps/cNxL2L8miqyf8oAF6)
4. Good Times Ink

   - https://goodtimesink.jp/ja/ (Mostly Japanese-English bilingual, lots of photos, price list, etc.)
   - 78 Google feedback with 5.0 average score, no negative feedback
   - 14-min train ride from JR Osaka Station
   - [Map](https://g.page/goodtimesink?share)

Notes: I myself have no tattoo/irezumi and do not live in Osaka. I live elsewhere in Japan and have been interested in getting one myself. In my experience of checking tattoo shops near where I live, in most cases you have to contact them in advance, tell/show them what you want, verify the prices, etc. Also, I'm not sure about your age but in Japan one has to be over 18 years old to be allowed to have one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your research, I very much appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to be of help!